# How do I get the PoW nonce of a specific block in solidity?

Tags: solidity, blockchain, blocks, nonce, randomness

[This](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/61003/how-to-get-the-pow-hash-of-a-specific-block) question doesn't have an answer that shows how to get the PoW `nonce` for a specific block internally from within Solidity.

From my understanding in Ethereum `nonce` is used for an account's tx increment count whereas in Bitcoin it's the PoW trial by error variable, so I'm not sure if there's a more correct term for it in this ecosystem.

Could someone please answer if it's possible to get the `nonce` for a specific block and if so how? Also is say the latest block's `nonce` a more random number than say its difficulty, timestamp, etc?

Answer (score 0):

I think you're confusing `blocknumber` with `txs nonce` and using them interchangeable

Comment: Isn't the `blocknumber` the block count from genesis? which is different from the PoW nonce solution for a particular block?  Whereas the tx nonce would be the tx count for a given account which is unrelated to PoW.